# Alter the returned value inside a query builder query in Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get a price from my database that is stored as an integer. An example of a value that I am getting is `3999` and I want it returned as `$39.99`. If the value is in the database `NULL` I want the value to be returned as `"N/A"`.

What I am doing currently works but it uses a for-loop were I suspect that I could do this in the query itself.

```
$query = AccesscodeHeader::where('channel_partner_id', '=', $channelPartnerId);
$results = $query->get();

foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
    $result->price = $result->price != null ? "$" . number_format(($result->price/100), 2, '.', '') : "N/A";
    $result->remaining = $result->quantity - $result->used;
}
```

Am I able to get the value in the desired format in the query itself or is this best done in the for-loop?

Comment: I struggled to come up with a proper title. I don't think "Alter" is the right word but I couldn't think of any better titles. Please suggest an edit to the title if you have a suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a couple of accessors in your `AccesscodeHeader` model.

```php
public function getFormattedPriceAttribute()
{
    if (!$this->price) return "N/A";

    return '$'.number_format($this->price/100, 2, '.', '');
}

public function getRemainingAttribute()
{
    return $this->quantity - $this->used;
}
```

```
$query = AccesscodeHeader::where('channel_partner_id', '=', $channelPartnerId);
$results = $query->get();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    dump($result->formatted_price);
    dump($result->remaining);
}
```

It IS possible to make your database do this formatting for you too, but the query would not look very nice.

It would end up as something like this (if you're using MySQL)

```php
$query = AccesscodeHeader::select(
    DB::raw('IF(ISNULL(price), "N/A" , CONCAT("$", ROUND(price/100, 2))) AS formatted_price'),
    DB::raw('quantity - used AS remaining'),
    // other selected columns/expressions
)
->where('channel_partner_id', '=', $channelPartnerId);
$results = $query->get();

foreach ($results as $result) {
    dump($result->formatted_price);
    dump($result->remaining);
}
```

Comment: Personally I prefer the first solution you provided but my company loves complex raw sql so I am going to go with the second selection. I've added DB::raw to select `id`, `quantity`, and `used` but other than that there are no changes to the second solution.

Comment: Should I edit your answer to make it match exactly what I did?

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I added a comment about other possible selected columns. If you want to convince them of adopting the first solution, a strong argument is maintainability. You'll have to rewrite that query whenever you need the formatted price whereas you only need to write the accessor logic in a single place.

Comment: I'm a young developer in an old company. Not nice looking SQL isn't the hill that I will choose to die on. Thanks for the help :)